# How to change font size of UTF16(Gujarati language) attributed string in function and use it to convert json nested data in swiftUI?

Tags: html, ios, json, swift, swiftui

i'm currently showing json data in SwiftUI list using function:

```html
@available(iOS 15, *)
func attributedString(from str: String) -> AttributedString {
    
    if let theData = str.data(using: .utf16 ) {
        do {
          
          
            let theString = try NSAttributedString( data: theData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil )
            
   
            return AttributedString(theString)
        } catch {  print("\(error)")  }
    }
    return AttributedString(str)
}
```

**and putting it in**

```html
import SwiftUI

struct lvl4: View {
    @State var books: [Buk] = [] 
    @State var selection: Buk?
  

 

    
    //ios 14 must to get the syntex right..
    @available(iOS 14, *)
    var body: some View {
        
        
        NavigationView {

            List(books) { book in
                ForEach(book.bookContent) { bookContent in
                    Section(header: Text(bookContent.title).font(.largeTitle) .fontWeight(.heavy)) {
                        OutlineGroup(bookContent.child, children: \.child) { item in
                            if #available(iOS 15, *) {
                               
                                Text(attributedString(from: item.title))

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
  

    
    // a file with valid json data for testing
    func loadData() {
        do {
            if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "સાગર મંથન_new", withExtension: "json") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                books = try JSONDecoder().decode([Buk].self, from: data) 
            }
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}

struct Buk: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var bookTitle: String = ""
    var isLive: Bool = false
    var userCanCopy: Bool = false
    var bookContent: [BookContent] = []
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bookTitle = "book_title"
        case isLive = "is_live"
        case userCanCopy = "user_can_copy"
        case bookContent = "book_content"
    }
}

struct BookContent: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title, type: String
    var child: [Child]
}

struct Child: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title, type: String
    var child: [Child]?
}
```

**i need to customise the font and size of the attributed string before it is returned as below which are very small by default when it is converted from utf16..** The code is for swiftUI and the function i created is for using it in parsing json file

[image] very small text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you would make an effort and find the answer yourself,
but I can see you could not. Try this:

```
func attributedString(from str: String, font: Font) -> AttributedString {
    if let theData = str.data(using: .utf16) {
        do {
            let theString = try NSAttributedString(data: theData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
            var attaString = AttributedString(theString)
            attaString.font = font  // <-- here
            return attaString
        } catch {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
    return AttributedString(str)
}
```

and call it like this:

```
Text(attributedString(from: item.title, font: Font.system(size: 30)))
```

Comment: When importing from json, though, it doesn't recognize italics: <i></i> or <em></em>. Not sure why.

Comment: don't know why this is happening. Best to ask a new question about this specific problem. Make sure you include a reproducible example code, when you ask the new question.

Comment: sorry I did not realised you are this `user`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000508/how-to-read-formatted-text-of-json-file-in-swiftui-14
 
In that question the `<i></i> or <em></em>` work well, however, when using a
 specific font, it seems to override the attributes of the string. Don't know why.

Comment: Thanks working dog. You have helped me a lot. I am using your fix, but it shows only tiny text so I'm looking at a fix. I've read a lot at Apple's documentation, but since I'm not a good coder, a lot of it goes over my head. If I ever find an answer, I'll  post to the original question.