# How to read formatted text of json file in swiftui 14?

Tags: swiftui

I have a json file that includes html styled text:
I need to maintain the included text formatting: bold, italic, underline, etc.

I am using SwiftUI and Xcode 14. I read the json into a SwiftUI list, then navigate to a detail page that shows the description text. I can't find any examples of how to maintain the formatted text that is in the json file. I've googled, looked at Apple Developer documentation and more, but to no avail.  Can anyone help me out with this. My application depends on properly formatted text. It seems odd that Apple wouldn't include something. This is easy in html and javascript. What am I missing? I am not a pro programmer and just starting out with SwiftUI. TIA

```
[                               
    { "imageurl": "1.png",
    "levelLongDesc":"A longer description",
    "id": "1.",
    "name": "A name)",
    "page": "Details",
    "description":"<p><b>E pluribus unum</b></p><b>Instructions.</b> Latin for “Out of many one”, is a motto requested by <i>Pierre Eugene du Simitiere</i> (originally Pierre-Eugène Ducimetière) and found in 1776 on the Seal of the United States, along with Annuit cœptis and Novus ordo seclorum, and adopted by an Act of Congress in 1782.</p><p>",
    "videoDemo":"myvideo"
    }...]

import SwiftUI
```

struct LandmarkDetail: View {
var landmark: Landmark
@State var Description = AttributedString("")
var body: some View {

```
    NavigationView{
    ScrollView {
        RectImage(image: landmark.image)
           
            .padding(.top, 30)
      
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        
            Divider()
        
            Text("\(landmark.name)")
          
        
            Text(landmark.description)
            .font(.title3)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .onAppear {
                (addStyling(landmark.description))
            }
            } .padding()
        
        }.navigationTitle(landmark.name)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
       
    }
private func addStyling(_ htmlString: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        var resultString = NSAttributedString()
        var data = Data()
        // Add the html data/ var in which you stored it
    data.append(Data(landmark.description.utf8))
        // Convert the attributed String
        do {
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
            resultString = attributedString
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return resultString
    }
}
```

Above is what my detail view looks like. I don't know where/how to add the attributes. I get errors with everything that I try. Again, thank you to the two of you who tried to help. -R

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `"description"` property of your decoded object model, is some simple html text,
you could use `AttributedString` and `NSAttributedString` as shown
in this example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var description = AttributedString("")
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(description)
            .onAppear {
                let txt = """
        <p><b>E pluribus unum</b></p><b>Instructions.</b> Latin for “Out of many one”, is a motto requested by <i>Pierre Eugene du Simitiere</i> (originally Pierre-Eugène Ducimetière) and found in 1776 on the Seal of the United States, along with Annuit cœptis and Novus ordo seclorum, and adopted by an Act of Congress in 1782.</p><p>
        """
                description = asAttribTxt(txt)
            }
    }
    
    func asAttribTxt(_ txt: String) -> AttributedString {
        let data = txt.data(using: .utf16)!  // <-- adjust to your needs
        do {
            let nsString = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
            return AttributedString(nsString)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return AttributedString(txt) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private func addStyling(_ htmlString: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        var resultString = NSAttributedString()
        var data = Data()
        // Add the html data/ var in which you stored it
        data.append(Data(htmlString.utf8))
        // Convert the attributed String
        do {
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
            resultString = attributedString
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return resultString
    }
```

Comment: I haven't quite gotten this to work yet, but I am very grateful for your help. When I can figure it all out, I'm certain this will do a nice job.